# Detect location for Android AppWidget without background location permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app for providing a weather forecast for a chosen location, which includes a widget.  As an option, the user can choose for the app and widget to show weather for the device's location, which is clearly a useful feature for the user.

For this, location permission is required (at least `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`).  And for the widget, because it (optionally) updates every e.g. hour in the background, without an app open in the foreground, this requires background location permission to be granted (`ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`) in order to get the latest device location at the time the widget updates.

But because of a [tightening of policy](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/safer-location-access.html) taking effect, updates to my app are now being rejected by Google.  Apparently I have to remove the background location permission.  Which is a shame because it is (a) clearly a useful feature from a user perspective; (b) entirely optional... the user does not have to grant it if they do not want to... the user is not forced into it and there is an explanation given as to why background location permission is required for a widget... the app itself is still usable (with detected location) without granting background location permission.

Is there any way to get the device's location for use in a widget, without the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission?  Currently I am using the following to get the location with the `FusedLocationProviderClient` :

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new LocationOnCompleteListener(context, listener, appWidgetId));
```

Comment: I salute your persistence, investigation details and the fact that you shared all these!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer: (a) it isn't possible to get the device's location for use in a widget without background permission; and (b) Google is losing the plot with its raft of new policies.

From what I have gleaned from a frustrating email exchange with Google, the upshot is that any app that has a **widget** that provides a "use device location" feature as an **option** (i.e. entirely optional... user choice and all that), and otherwise uses a fixed location of the user's choosing, must now make "use device location" as the **default**, so that app reviewers can see the "prominent disclosure" pop up *without having to go into a menu* (to enable the option)... so that they can tick this particular checkbox in their review checklist.

Apparently the use of background location must also be "critical to the primary purpose of the app".  As it's an *option* (it can be turned on or off), I guess this means that it is not "critical to the primary purpose of the app".  So maybe the upshot is that this useful *option* needs to be dropped completely.  Or maybe I need to make it a requirement that the user enables background location, even if they don't want or need it?

What happened to user choice?  Trust in the user to use their intelligence to make an informed choice?  Gone.

Comment: I'm going through the same deal with my app. And I agree with you - it's a ridiculous decision on their part. But it's a clear symptom of how much ill intentioned data collecting companies are exploiting user ignorance. I was hoping Google would at least provide some api to fetch the location THEY are collecting in background as the ill intentioned company they are, but I'm not sure if there is one right now

Comment: I went through some of the top 20 apps in my category (weather) and every one I checked was using background location.  So either they will face the same problem, or somehow they have managed to get their usage accepted.  It may be that, as the hard deadline approaches, Google will have to soften its marking scheme slightly, to avoid half the (useful and genuine) apps on the Play Store disappearing overnight.

Comment: What is most infuriating for me is that they set up run-time permission request procedures to give the user complete choice about what permissions they grant and what they don't, and now they say that the user is not to be trusted and Google will decide instead whether to grant this particular permission.  OK I understand that background location is more open to abuse, and some users just click OK to anything, but this is a good example of dumbing down.

Comment: Yeah, that's most likely public relations work, since "evil location tracking" is trending. I wonder if in the next trend they will go after camera permissions, making camera apps justify why they use it :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filling in the Permissions Declaration Form for location permissions in the Google Play console?

[image: Permissions Declaration Form]

Comment: Indeed, yes I have. That is what got me into this mess to start with. I had hoped that Google would understand that it is a useful feature, and justified in view of the benefit... for users of this app sold from their Play Store (making them money in the process).  The user can choose never to grant this permission... isn't that the whole point of run-time permissions??  To give full control to the user?  Now Google seems to be taking that choice away by deciding for themselves up-front whether background location is justified or not. Do they not trust developers or users anymore?

Comment: Are you sure you need `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` for the widget? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: When a widget refreshes its content (e.g. every hour) it can no longer retrieve the latest device location to use as a basis for the widget content (weather forecast), because there is no app visible in the foreground at the time.  This is exactly the sort of thing that `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is there for, and the user is in full control of it.

Comment: What happens is that I have to fall back on the last known location, which may have been six months ago when the user last opened the app... most users use an auto updating widget and never need to open the app itself.

Comment: `FusedLocationProviderClient` just returns a `null` location.

Answer (score 0):

An optional workaround (with degradation of user experience):

If you provide a `PendingIntent` with `setOnClickPendingIntent` for something inside the widget:

```java
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, createRefreshIntent(context, appWidgetId));

private static @NonNull PendingIntent createRefreshIntent(@NonNull Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = createUpdateIntent(context, appWidgetId);
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") // New flag shouldn't cause a problem in older versions.
    int flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, flags);
}

private static @NonNull Intent createUpdateIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull int... appWidgetIds) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
    return intent;
}
```

that is considered a foreground operation and you **will** have the permission ready to use.

So if the user keeps tapping "refresh", that's foreground, but if you want to do it automatically every 30 minutes, that's background depending on whether the user happens to be staring at the launcher screen or not.